# Is there a way to runModal on two windows?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nswindow

As in...

I have an action in my application that pops up a window and an accompanying panel of options. I want to block interaction with the original window and focus solely on the popped-up window and its panel.

I can easily do this if I just required the single popped up-window and not the panel. I can also enable and disable objects in the original window but I would like to do this more elegantly. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a [sheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Sheets.html) attached to your main window instead of popping up a modal window.

Because a sheet is window-modal not application-modal, you can still interact with other windows in your app while the sheet is displayed (such as your panel).

Comment: My problem with sheets for this situation is that they've very particular behavior that only feels appropriate for certain situations. My popped-up window with a separate options panel is a print preview window that is often bigger than its parent window. It typically fills the height of the screen and doesn't lend itself well to being a sheet in either appearance or its priority.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I still believe that it's the right UI for the situation you describe. There's precedence for large sheets, have a look at the version control commit sheet in Xcode 4, for example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the VCCS so I'll have a look at that now and get back to this question very soon. Thanks Rob!

Comment: I'm not using Xcode 4 and not currently in a position to upgrade and haven't had much look finding an example of what you're speaking about on Google. Unless I'm misunderstanding that a sheet *must* slide out of its parent window (including the example you mentioned in Xcode 4), I think this would be an impractical and ugly UI element for a large, portrait size UI element. If its parent window is not large and centered, it would flow off the screen. The developer docs mention its intended for dialogs and I wouldn't consider what I want to display a dialog. I very much appreciate the advice.